# Visual C++ Express How do I just run the app?

Tags: visual-c++

I don't see how to just run an app in Visual C++ Express.  Debug option is right there but how about running the app?  I checked each button on above and right clicked everything I could but I don't see the option to just run it? Without debugging. I don't mind debugging but I lose the console screen that main is running its loop in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by pressing Ctrl+F5. Or you could add it as a menu item (found this on the www):

Tools -> Customize- > Commands tab -> Rearrange Commands -> Select Debug from Menu Bar dropdownlist -> Add -> Select Debug from Categories, Select Start without debugging from Commands -> OK.

Comment: Thanks for posting the complete steps.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The option might not be available by default on your toolbar, To set the **Start without debugging button**. You can goto and select **Tools** > **Customize** > **Debug** and then drag n drop it on your toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Did not see the Start Without Debugging option Under Tools->Customize->Debug Perhaps because its Express Version ...

Comment: @Androider: I've added another snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into the IDE, I know that with default keybindings(keyboard shortcuts):

- <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> will start *without debugging*
- <kbd>F5</kbd> will start with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Solution Configuration to 'Release', which strips the majority of debugging information, but no matter what you do, if you execute it within the IDE it will take control of it to a certain extent.

If I want to run a console app without interference from the IDE I just open another command prompt, *cd* to the debug/release directory (as appropriate) and execute it from there.